# Java Application with H2 Database

Tags: java, database, h2, raspbian

I have a java application which retrievs data from a H2 database.
The database and the application are installed on the same computer.
Now when i run the application under my Windows 10 pc everything works fine, but when i copy the java application onto my Raspberry Pi 2 B(Raspbian Jessie) it does not work anymore. 
On both systems, I installed, the H2 database, which I can access via the browser interface, and also java.

The error on the Raspberry Pi is:

```
Feb 26, 2016 2:39:26 AM HelperPackage.DatabaseConnection startConnection
SEVERE: null
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "PRODUKTE" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT Name, Datum, Anzahl, Warnzeitpunkt, ID
FROM PRODUKTE
ORDER BY Datum;
```

You can see the whole error message [here](http://pastebin.com/CNjJjdFm).

It looks like my table does not exist on my Raspberry Pi but when I take a look at the browser interface of my H2 database, the table is there.

My connection is created with the strings you can see in the .getConnection Method (import from java.sql.DriverManager).

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test","sa","");
```

Like I said, the application works fine on my Windows 10 pc.

Libraries I use:

- pdfbox-app-2.0.0-RC3 for printing
- h2-1.4.190 for the connection to the database

Comment: I'd verify that the two systems are connecting to the same database in `{user.home}`

Comment: It is not really the same database. I installed one H2 database on my Windows pc and one on my Raspberry pi.

I did not configure anything on one of the h2 databases, besides the creation of the tables, so everything should provide the same circumstances. 

The only difference should be the OS.

Comment: Yep, but `~/test` will make a database in the `{user.home}` on each system. When browsing via the web interface, I would make sure you're connecting to the correct database for the system

Comment: Ok, but it is not possible for the Raspberry that it's connecting to the wrong database because the Raspberry Pi is not connected to any network, and the only database on the Pi is the H2 database.

Maybe I am missunderstanding you... I am going to check {user.home}

Comment: I checked it and nothing seems wrong. Two files in my /home/pi directory, test.mv.db and test.trace.db.   Should I try a fixed path, so that the connection string would look like this: "jdbc:h2:/home/pi"?

Comment: OH MY GOD    fixed path worked....  does this make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Soft-code explicit path

The expansion of the [tilde (~)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) is not exactly standard.

Funny… I was concerned about this when I first saw [that example in the H2 doc](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc). I vaguely recall experiencing other situations where the tilde failed as a symbol for “my home directory/folder”, unrelated to H2 or JDBC.

For my own work, out of my vague paranoia, I have been using this soft-coded call instead of the tilde in my H2 JDBC URL:

```
System.getProperty( "user.home" )
```

Something like this.

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:h2:" + System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/test" , "scott" , "tiger" );
```

See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for more info on [`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

---

This problem reminded me of a similar problem when I have seen situations where [`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) failed to resolve because of some interplay between underlying libraries, forcing the explicit use of `127.0.0.1`.

If you ever had time it might be interesting to dig through the H2 source to discover where exactly the tilde expansion failed on the Pi. Something about the Pi’s Java implementation? Or a library in the Pi’s Linux being called by Java?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a dynamic path like ~/test I used a fixed path like /home/pi to solve the problem.