# Hibernate update causes tests to fail with error - Table "REVINFO" not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I updated my Spring boot version and that caused the hibernate version to update as well. These are the versions:

```
Spring boot - 2.7.0
Hibernate-core - 5.6.9
Hibernate-envers - 5.3.20.Final
```

It was updated from Spring boot version `2.3.9.RELEASE` and Hibernate-core version `5.4.28`.

When I run the test suite, I see the error `Table REVINFO not found`:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "REVINFO" not found; SQL statement:
alter table insights.templateTable_aud add constraint FK9dw2kc3x0ti0c559slp64avtx foreign key (rev) references revinfo [42102-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
```

I tried creating the revinfo table in my `schema.sql` but I still get the same error. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What are the versions you updated from? Maybe the table name is in caps while you defined is as lowercase?
You can try to increase the log level to log the sql statements: `-Dhibernate.show_sql=true` 
Or set the table name with ` @Table(name= "revinfo")`

Comment: It was updated from Spring boot version `2.3.9.RELEASE` and Hibernate-core version `5.4.28`. The table revinfo is supposed to be generated automatically for Audited tables, so it's not something that I created.

Comment: Not sure why upgrading Hibernate and Spring boot would cause the error. But you can set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` explicitly and the standard Hibernate property values are `none`, `validate`, `update`, `create`, and `create-drop`. Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to `create-drop` if no schema manager has been detected or `none` in all other cases. An embedded database is detected by looking at the Connection type and JDBC url. hsqldb, h2, and derby are candidates, and others are not.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.x/reference/html/howto.html#howto.data-initialization.using-jpa

Comment: Hi, uses the H2 database logs to know  to find out the real reason :https://stackoverflow.com/a/72712120/4017037

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the revinfo table is automatically generated; it's not explicitly defined in the Spring project. The classes that have an **@Audited** tag above them have an audited table automatically generated for them.

Check whether you need that audit log table to be there and if there is no need try removing the **@Audited** annotation and try restarting your server.